# How can I properly format this?

Tags: formatting

[image]

Can I use another proper format instead of this?
This is my code

```
(s_{d+i})_k=\sum_{j=0}^{d-1}\lambda_j(s_{j+i})_k \qquad  & 0\leqslant i\leqslant d-1\\  & 1\leqslant k\leqslant d
```

Comment: I have slightly changed the second solution, you might want to look at it.

Comment: @egreg what actually change? ps with the new mod I get some errors

Comment: I exploited `array` features better; but you need `\usepackage{array}` in addition to your other loaded packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you need to stack the conditions seems to point to a two column format, otherwise just continuing on the same line would be sufficient.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\[
(s_{d+i})_k=\sum_{j=0}^{d-1}\lambda_j(s_{j+i})_k \qquad
\begin{aligned}
& 0\leqslant i\leqslant d-1\\
& 1\leqslant k\leqslant d
\end{aligned}
\]
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can get less vertical space between the conditions with `array`, also with alignment of the inequality symbols:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,array}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\[
(s_{d+i})_k=\sum_{j=0}^{d-1}\lambda_j(s_{j+i})_k \qquad
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{c>{{}}c<{{}}c>{{}}c<{{}}l}
0 &\leqslant& i &\leqslant& d-1\\
1 &\leqslant& k &\leqslant& d
\end{array}
\]
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
(s_{d+i})_k =\sum_{j=0}^{d-1}\lambda_j(s_{j+i})_k \tag*{\llap{$(0\leqslant i\leqslant d-1 ,\enspace 1\leqslant k\leqslant d)$}}
 \end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]